# Javascript - Change all numbers in a string to subscripts

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, subscript

I have an input box in which the user inputs a chemical formula.  I am displaying their input back to them in a table, with the following code in my javascript file.

```
document.getElementById("entered").innerHTML = userIn;
```

...where "userIn" is the "id" of the input box, and "entered" is the id of the data in my table row.

**Now, here's my question:**

Is there any way I can change all of the numbers in the formula to subscripts, but leaving the letters unchanged?  So if H2O2 is entered, only the 2's become subscripted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a simple regex replace as given below

```
document.getElementById("entered").innerHTML = userIn.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<sub>$1</sub>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XGbFH/)

Comment: Ahhh, yes that worked.  Using a regex just completely slipped my mind!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to surround all of the digits in `userIn` with `<sub></sub>` tags.  The following should work:

```
userIn.replace(/(\d+)/g, "<sub>$1</sub>");
```

The `+` in the regex will group a string of consecutive digits together and the tailing `g` in the regex says to replace all the strings of digits instead of just replacing the first string of digits in `userIn`.