# How to convert a string into chemical formula in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert a string "C11H15NO3" into chemical formula using subscript like C<sub>11</sub>H<sub>15</sub>NO<sub>3</sub>

How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you **need** to do this in JS? It can be done in plain HTML using the `<sub>` tag: https://jsfiddle.net/w37fz891/

Comment: Are all numbers in the string subscripted? What if you have a formula like `(CuSO4).5H2O`, should 5 be subscript here?

Comment: Hey, this question was answered before. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311116/javascript-change-all-numbers-in-a-string-to-subscripts

Answer (score 3):

You could split the array and map a new string with `sup` tags.

```js
var string = 'C11H15NO3',
    result = string
        .split(/(\d+)/)
        .map((s, i) => i % 2 ? `<sub>${s}</sub>` : s)
        .join('');

document.body.innerHTML += result;
```

Or you replace with a single statement by looking for numbers only.

```js
var string = 'C11H15NO3',
    result = string.replace(/\d+/g, '<sub>$&</sub>');

document.body.innerHTML += result;
```

Comment: Nina, Thanks a lot. It is working like charm! Can you give me some resource links where I can learn js and regular expressions like you?

Comment: @freedomn-m Nina's answer was perfect. Thank you for your help.